Victoria Metrics Export API - Export data and sampling
There are many ways to read data from victoria metrics database.

The query API /api/v1/query?query=...&time=...&step=...&timeout=...
The query API /api/v1/query_range?query=...&start=...&end=...&step=...&timeout=...
The export API /api/v1/export?match[]=<timeseries_selector_for_export>
.
.
.

I'm in a situation where I cannot use the two first methods (query) and I'm heavily using the /api/v1/export. I hit the wall recently when I found that the export api didn't support step argument like the api /api/v1/query_range, unless I didn't dig enough in the documentation to find it.
So, is there any way to do a sampling while exporting data from victoria metrics? eg step=5 means I want to skip 5 timestamps. If the total number of values in the database for the given selector is 100, the export must return ~25.

What's the reason of not using /query_range for this purpose?

Sampling via step is supported only via /query_range APIs - see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#range-query
Step in /query API has a bit different meaning, but you can see it in the docs.
/export API returns raw data, as it is. So it doesn't support sampling or any other data modifications.

The last part of your answer should be a comment IMHO
